# Avoid Passing arrow function params to another function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm using express and am using an arrow function to handle my `req,res` params. I'm delegating this `req,res` to another helper function though.

I.e.

```
app.get("/Model/:id", (req, res) => { Handler.model(req, res) });
```

My question is if I can avoid that redundancy and just do something like

```
app.get("/Model/:id", Handler.model(req, res));
```

Comment: Have you tried: `app.get("/Model/:id", Handler.model);`. Read this article to learn more about the difference of passing things by reference/value: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/

Comment: good but not safe, if Handler.model returns something, which not accepted by `app.get(` can cause issue. Better you should not always delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do a η-reduction:

```
app.get("/Model/:id", Handler.model);
```

However you might have to `bind` it:

```
app.get("/Model/:id", Handler.model.bind(Handler));
```

Notice that unlike your original arrow function, this does pass an arbitrary amount of arguments to the `model` method, not exactly two, and it does return the return value of the `model` method instead of nothing (`undefined`). It depends on `app.get` and `Handler.model` whether they can deal with those minor differences.